# derby sql insert

Tags: sql, derby

I'm trying to insert values in my database
This is the statement I try to execute:

```
insert into leverancier (id,naam,straat,nr,postcode,plaats,telefoon) 
    values (1,"stef","bosstraat",88,9240,"Zele",null);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 42X04: Column 'stef' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'stef' is not a column in the target table.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing strings should be delimited with single quotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To insert a string, like `"stef"`, don't use double quotes but single quotes: `'stef'`. Here's how the statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO leverancier 
  (id, naam, straat, nr, postcode, plaats, telefoon) 
VALUES 
  (1,'stef', 'bosstraat', 88, 9240, 'Zele', NULL);
```

The error you get `Column 'stef' is either not in any table ...` is because double quotes are used for table and column names. So reading `"stef"`, the parser assumes you are referring to a column named `stef`.